# android : HIDL to AIDL

Tags: android, aidl, hidl

Recenetly google is asking chip vendor to change HAL from HIDL to AIDL.
My question is : As a chip vendor, I can porting original service side method from HIDL to AIDL. But how about client side? Does client side need to modify their code?

Be more specific, does HIDL and AIDL generate same .h file for client to use? (at least same methd in .h)

Answer (score 0):

If the client-side is using the Android framework, so it won't be affected by porting to AIDL. Because you're porting the HAL implemantation.